# How to specify the task's user identity "Pool default user (Admin)" in the azure batch account?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-batch

I'm trying to create several batch tasks from the Powershell script and looking for how specifying User Identity. Dotnet core APIs support this specifying, but nothing for Azure-CLI.

When I run a script below I get an error from my PowerShell script, which says that there are not enough permissions to perform this action:

```
az batch account login -g $resourceGroup -n $batchAccountName 
az batch task create --job-id $BatchJobId `
    --task-id "DeployIdHere" `
    --command-line $cmdCommand `
    --account-name $batchAccountName `
    --debug `
    --verbose `
    --output table
```

I assumed to find something like `--elevation-level Admin` but seems I don't get how it should look likes in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `--json-file` flag to create a task with specifying User Identity in the command `az batch task create --job-id myjobtest --json-file .\task.json`.

For format, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-cli-python-samples/blob/master/batch/run-job/tasks.json

You also could add multiple tasks with the admin. A task JSON file will be something like this:

```
{
    "id": "mytasktest123",
    "commandLine": "/bin/bash -c \"sudo ls\"",
    "waitForSuccess": true,
    "userIdentity": {
        "autoUser": {
          "elevationLevel": "admin",
          "scope": "pool"
        },
        "userName": null
      }
    }
```

Result
[image]

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Your solution saved my time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> which says that there are not enough permissions to perform this action

When you use `az batch account login -g $resourceGroup -n $batchAccountName` login, it uses *Auzre AD authentication*, it uses the credential of the account which you logged in with `az login`.

If you use the command with `--shared-key-auth` parameter, it uses the *Shared Key authentication*, but your account also needs the permission to do `Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts/listKeys/action` action. At first I thought `Reader` role is enough, but per my test, it does not have the permission to list keys of batch account.

So to fix the issue, you could let the `Owner` of the `subscription/batch account` give your user account which logged in with `az login` as an `Owner` or `Contributor` role. Navigate to the subscription/batch account in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search for your user account(or service principal), add it as `Owner`/`Contributor` role, details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal). Then use [`az account clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-clear) to clear the local cache and run `az batch account login -g $resourceGroup -n $batchAccountName` again, `az batch task create` will work fine.

> How to specify the task's user identity “Pool default user (Admin)” in the azure batch account?

The way is to use `--json-file` parameter, based on your requirement, specify the `elevationLevel` with `nonadmin` or `admin` in the `.json` file like below.

`batch.json` file:

```
{
  "id": "task1",
  "commandLine": "bash -c 'echo hello'",
  "userIdentity": {
    "autoUser": {
      "scope": "task",
      "elevationLevel": "admin"
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample**:

```
az batch task create --job-id myjob --json-file C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\batch.json
```

[image]